# MYSQL two tables, information and grouping

Tags: mysql

Ok, I'm not even sure where to begin on this one. I am so new to mysql I can't wrap my head around it.

I've got two tables:

```
Table1: resources
Column1: id (primary,autoinc)
Column2: memberID
Column3: resource1
Column4: resource2
```

and

```
Table2: groups
Column1: memberid1
Column2: memberid2
Column3: memberid3
Column4: memberid4
Column5: memberid5
Column6: memberid6
Column7: groupID
```

What I'm attempting to do is to manage resource groups between members. Each member will have their information in table1, and then groupings of 6 members each in table2 will complete a specific group. If a person is deleted from table1, table2 would have any columns matching that set to NULL.

My question is what would the most efficient way be to display each group, and populate with the member ID & associated resources?

Edit-

The output could even be:

```
Cicle: ID# Members: memberid1, memberid2, memberid3, memberid4, memberid5, memberid6
```

And then clicking the ID to display the resources of each member.

Comment: Are the `id` and `groupID` columns the same?

Comment: Rather than having memberidN columns on groups you'd probably be better off with a third table, group_member table which has a groupId and memberId.

Comment: The id & groupID aren't the same. they're just auto-increment primary keys.

And what do you mean of a 3rd table? basically all the member data is in table 1, and table 2 would just be for tracking group members in each circle.  Explain a bit further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a separate table that would handle members individually and per record instead of per column as in your case. So, that when a member is deleted it could be easily removed from the group. So, it would probably like:

```
 Table1: resources
 Column1: id (primary,autoinc)
 Column2: memberID
 Column3: resource1
 Column4: resource2

 Table2: groups
 Column1: groupID
 Column2: groupName

 Table3: groupsmember
 Column1: groupID
 Column2: memberID
```

You could probably have Member's table like:

```
 Table4: members
 Column1: memberID
 Column2: memberLastname
 Column3: memberFirstname
```

Then you could use GROUP_CONCAT to see the members (6) of each group:

```
SELECT groupID, GROUP_CONCAT(memberID)
FROM groupsmember
GROUP BY groupID
```

See example [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: Ahhhhhhh ok I see the benefit of the third table now. Thanks, I'll give this a go to see if I can get it working right after finals. Will mark it as answered if it works as intended.